# Collect initialized ActiveModel instances within method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I get all instantiated ActiveModel instance during method execution?

```
class Foo
  def some_method
    Post.new title: 'First title'
    Post.new title: 'Second title'
  end
end

module Launcher
  def self.launch!
    fooser = Foo.new
    new_posts = Post.watch do
      fooser.some_method()
    end

    # new_posts => #<Enumerator [#2 initialized Posts#]>
    # Some logic for saving all these initialized objects at once
  end
end

Launcher.launch!
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a relation not just an array? Also, do you need this to be before storing the records to the database or after?

Comment: It can be Array. Its like DSL, and I need to collect all initialized objects during method execution.

Comment: If you want `Foo#some_method` to return both objects, then you need to response to be an array.

Comment: But I'm not sure what you mean by "save all objects at once". If you expect this to be done in a single database query, then it's possible but not via this approach!

Comment: By design I dont want make some_method() always return array. I need this method to be independent. "save all objects at once" - it would be done with activerecord-import later after collection all initialized objects.

Comment: Put the objects in an instance variable? I don't really understand that you're trying to achieve. It almost feels as though you'd just like to set global variables and call arbitrary other methods that can access them... Which works, but is not a good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the source, the easiest way would be to just return an array from your method.

```
def some_method
  [
    Post.new title: 'First title',
    Post.new title: 'Second title',
  ]
end
```

However, I assume your solution is not that simple and you actually want to collect all models initiated during the block execution.

The simplest way would be to use `after_initialize` for that and store the records into for example a class variable.

```
def self.watch
  @records = []
  @watching = true
  yield
ensure
  @watching = false
  @records
end

def self.record_initialized(record)
  @records << record if @watching
end

after_initialize { |record| record.class.record_initialized(record) }
```

If you at some point want to insert them using one query, look into `.insert_all`

Comment: Ok, it is a good idea with after_initialize, it is close what I need. But how can I dynamically set this callback only around fooser.some_method() call? Without setting it globally to all Post model.

Comment: I implemented the .watch method to work as you described. If you call watch with a block, all records initialized in that block will be returned by .watch. This is what all the code is for. It's still somewhat dangerous, because if watch is called a 2nd time in itself, then the outer watch will return the wrong result.

Comment: Is there any way to set after_initialize callback temporary? Not for all model Post, but for Relation object for example, kind a singleton callback. Or include module directly to Relation object

Comment: It's possible, but usually not worth it. Having it everywhere, but only run conditionally is usually a better solution. Is there any specific case that you have in mind?